# Python list of dictionaries - for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I use this piece of code:

```
for key, value in test_session_results[test_env].iteritems():
        my_dict = {"test_case": key, "status": value}
        new_dict.update(my_dict)
```

my_dict always has the different value and I want to append those values to a list, to create a list of dictionaries. I've tried with update but I guess it is not used for this purposes.

Comment: Because a dictionary not contain two same keys. Instead of `new_dict.update(my_dict)` try `[new_dict.update(my_dict)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty list and append the dictionaries to that list.

```
a = []

for key, value in test_session_results[test_env].iteritems():
       my_dict = {"test_case": key, "status": value}
       a.append(my_dict)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).